# Python Tkinter - how to get access to the parent's class dictionary from start window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

It tries to display the slider which is responsible for setting the age of logged-in user. The data is downloaded during the user's verification. I want the slider to take the default value of  self.controller.fromDB['age'].But also other data such name or email of the user. When trying to use dictionary self.controller.fromDB['age'], key error appears.Unless there is another possibility to solve this problem ?

```
class FirstApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.userInfo = {}
        self.connection = myconnutils.getConnection()
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        for F in (LoginPage, MainPage):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("LoginPage")

    def __del__(self):
        self.connection.close()

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

class LoginPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.cursor= self.controller.cursor
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Login:")
        label2.pack(side="left", fill="x", pady=10)
        label2.place(x=310, y=90, in_=self)
        self.e1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.e1.pack(side="left", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.e1.place(x=370, y=90, in_=self)
        label3 = tk.Label(self, text="Password:")
        label3.pack(side="left", fill="x", pady=10)
        label3.place(x=310, y=120, in_=self)
        self.e2 = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
        self.e2.pack(side="left", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.e2.place(x=370, y=120, in_=self)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Login",
                            command=self._login_btn_clicked,width = 25)
        button1.pack()
        button1.place(x=310, y=150, in_=self)

    def _login_btn_clicked(self):
        username = self.e1.get()
        password = self.e2.get()
        hash = hashlib.sha512()
        hash.update(('%s%s' % ('salt', password)).encode('utf-8'))
        password_hash = hash.hexdigest()
        sql = "Select COUNT(id) AS count,age, from users Where username = %s AND password = %s"
        self.cursor.execute(sql, (username,password_hash))
        fromDB = self.cursor.fetchall()
        if fromDB[0]['count'] > 0:
            self.controller.userInfo['age'] = fromDB[0]['age']
            self.controller.show_frame("MainPage")

class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Main Page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack()
        self.connection = controller.connection
        self.cursor = self.controller.cursor

        self.w = tk.Scale(self, from_=0, to=200, orient='horizontal')
        self.w.pack()
        self.w.set(7)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Print",
                                 command=self.funcPrint)
        button.pack()

    def funcPrint(self):
        ee=self.w.get()
        print(ee)
        print(self.controller.fromDB['age'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = FirstApp()
    app.geometry('{}x{}'.format(300, 300))
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `fromDB` is a local variable within `_login_btn_clicked()`.  It is not accessible from anywhere else, and doesn't even exist at the time `funcPrint()` tries to use it.

Comment: @jasonharper how can I store user data(from database)? And how could I use them in a different class?

Answer (score 0):

As @jasonharper mentions, `fromDB` is a local variable within `_login_btn_clicked()` which means that it exists for that scope (and scopes that exists within `_login_btn_clicked`).

The fact of the matter is that you don't specifically want `fromDB`; you say in your question that you want access to *age and other user data*. The other data doesn't exist in `fromDB`, so getting access to `fromDB` wouldn't help you there.

You do, however, have another dictionary called `userInfo` on your controller (`FirstApp`) which is where you store `age` and- assumably- where you intend to store stuff like Username, Login Token, etc.

So, just change your code to `self.controller.userInfo['age']` and plan on storing/retrieving in that manner for other information.